# Compatibility between R stargazer and LaTeX \textsubscript

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I would like to combine `stargazer` (from the same named R package) with `\textsubscript` to end up with a LaTeX table that looks roughly like this.

[image]

My first approach

```
dat <- data.frame(count = 4000, value = .4)
rownames(dat) <- "NDVI\textsubscript{3g}"

library(stargazer)
stargazer(dat, summary = FALSE)
```

created this LaTeX tabular code (shortened version)

```
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & count & value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
NDVI    extsubscript\{3g\} & $4,000$ & $0.400$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
```

i.e., `\t` was interpreted as TAB. I found [here](http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html) that it is possible to avoid such behavior by adding a second backslash like

```
dat2 <- data.frame(count = 4000, value = .4)
rownames(dat2) <- "NDVI\\textsubscript{3g}"

stargazer(dat2, summary = FALSE)
```

but now, the resulting code looks even more weird

```
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & count & value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
NDVI\textbackslash textsubscript\{3g\} & $4,000$ & $0.400$ \\
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue from the R side, i.e., without manually editing the LaTeX code after it has been created via `stargazer`?

Comment: Is `gsub`-ing a stargazer output an option?

Comment: `gsub` would definitely be a nice R work-around, but I was wondering whether the above issue could be taken care of by `stargazer` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the row names via `covariate.labels`

```
stargazer(dat, summary = FALSE, covariate.labels = "NDVI\\textsubscript{3g}")
```

Which produces the desired output

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: dim., nov. 19, 2017 - 21:49:46
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
NDVI\textsubscript{3g} & count & value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
1 & $4,000$ & $0.400$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```